# Load js function only once onload

Tags: javascript, php

I want this JS function to be called only once when the page is loaded .

```
function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
}

function showPosition(position) {
x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
"<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
    window.location.href = "?    latitude="+position.coords.latitude+"&longitude="+position.coords.longitude;
    var flag = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's going into an infinite loop because you are redirecting the page with

```
window.location.href = "?    latitude="+position.coords.latitude+"&longitude="+position.coords.longitude;
```

every time the page loads. Instead you could do something like this for showPosition():

```
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
    var query = "?    latitude="+position.coords.latitude+"&longitude="+position.coords.longitude;
    var stateObj = { query: query };
    history.pushState(stateObj, "query added", query);
    var flag = true;
}
```

This will add the query parameters to the URL without refreshing the page. For more details on `history.pushState()`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 0):

Your code it's a big closure! It generate new request on this step:

```
window.location.href = "?latitude="+position.coords.latitude+"&longitude="+position.coords.longitude;
```

You can use different ways:

1. simple parse `window.location.href` on load and don't ask location if
   `(window.location.href.indexOf('?')!=-1)`
2. mark client with browser data storage or coockies, and check it before ask location.
3. use Ajax for send location info to server:

   ```
   var req = (window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   req.onreadystatechange=function(){if((req.readyState==4)&&(req.status==200)){ console.log('location was sended to server'); }};
   req.open("GET","?latitude="+position.coords.latitude+"&longitude="+position.coords.longitude,true);
   req.send(null);
   ```

Comment: it was working for sometime.... but now am getting error r is not defined in the browser console....

Comment: it's my fastcopypaste error =) in this code `((r.readyState==4)&&(r.status==200))` must be `req`, in my original code I was used variable `r` and I have changed it to `req` for more understandable... I have updated my answer, so you can try it again

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) event handler:

```
<body onload="getLocation()">
```

This will fire as soon as the page is ready.

Alternatively, you can use jQuery's [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getLocation();
});
```